# why slash URL runs with all of other URLs in the middleware of NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why I enter `http://localhost:3000/product` on the browser, the output will be both outputs of `'/'` and `'/product'`?

Please look at this snippet code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


// http://localhost:3000/product
app.use('/product', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log('In product page');
    res.send('<h1>Product Page</h1>');
});


// http://localhost:3000/
app.use('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log('In main page');
    res.send('<h1>Main Page</h1>');
});


app.listen(3000);
```

This image is my app's output.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in express whatever you define with app.use() is middleware and it always executes until and unless it has some path defined

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log('In main page');
    res.send('<h1>Main Page</h1>');
});
```

above will always execute because it contains root path and every url has root path

Check this link for further info https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

You should define your routing with express router using app.get("/") or app.post("/") and it will help for more info https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Why ```console.log('In main page');``` will be run but ```res.send('<h1>Main Page</h1>');``` won't be run?

Comment: Because of my html page output is "Product Page" but output in terminal is similar to image on my question.

Comment: as you know in node.js everything is asynchronus so both middleware got executed but the response got overriden by the  middleware app.use('/product', (req, res, next)=>{ }) as it is following top to bottom approach

Answer (score 1):

It could have multiple reasons. One that I think of right now is that the browser requests `http://localhost:3000/`[`favicon.ico`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) automatically after `product.html`, which triggers the `use('/', ...)` route.

Maybe you should use [`app.all(...)`](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#app.all) instead of [`app.use(...)`](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#app.use), to avoid this "wildcard" on every path that should rather be a 404 page.

Comment: Could I do anything that doesn't request for faveicon.ico?

Answer (score 1):

The app.use() method is used to bind application level middleware. Not for accepting GET request as you are expecting.

You should use

```
    // http://localhost:3000/product
    app.get('/product', (req, res)=>{
        console.log('In product page');
        res.send('<h1>Product Page</h1>');
    });


    // http://localhost:3000/
    app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        console.log('In main page');
        res.send('<h1>Main Page</h1>');
    });
```